# How to scale feature by column?

Tags: numpy, keras, scikit-learn

I believe i have to scale my features differently. Is there an easy way to scale my features by column?

ie.

```
samples[:, 0] = preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler().fit_transform([:, 0])
samples[:, 1] = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform([:, 1])
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
samples["column1"] = preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler().fit_transform(samples["column1"])
samples["column2"] = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(samples["column2"])
```

You can do it like this if you want to scale columns differently.